# ¿Funcion sincrona a la espera de swal en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Lo que busco es que el hilo de ejecución de una función `X` quede a la espera del `swal`. Algo como esto

```
function x() {
    var t = false
  //Por aqui valida cosas

  //llega al swal

  swal({
    title: "¿Desea actualizar las demas cuentas?",
    text: "Esta a punto de registrar una cuenta que es nómina",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
    closeOnConfirm: true,
    closeOnCancel: true,

  }, function(isConfirm) {
    //Es en este punto que necesito detener la ejecucion de la función x a la espera de lo que haga con el swal

    if (isConfirm) {
        t = true;

    } else {


    }

  });

  if(t == true){ alert("Espero a que el swal diera respuesta")}
  //El problema es que para cuando la funcion llegue a este punto, la     variable t estará en false. Para cuando confirme el swal, la función ya habrá terminado su ejecución
}
```

Comment: ¿Por que no quisieras mover el código que _"se ejecutara una vez cerrado el swal"_ dentro de la función `function(isConfirm) {...`?

Comment: Buena pregunta. No en todos los casos la funcion llegara a ejecutar el bloque del swal, esta dentro de una condicion. La cuestión es que la función puede tomar varios caminos.

Comment: Entonces mete ese código en una función independiente que se llame desde ambas opciones

Comment: Necesito esperar el swal. No se usar bien el await, y no se si con eso funcione

Comment: Si estas usando [`bootstrap-sweetalert`](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) este no ha implementado `promises`, por lo que desde mi punto de vista tienes 2 opciones: buscar otro _plugin_ o "_sobrecargarlo_" e implentar `promises`